# What is an appropriate format for returning version-history of a resource via http

Tags: rest, http, version-control, rfc

I am designing a ReSTful web service which provides a versioned resource.
What is an appropriate return format (content-type) for returning a [version history](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5829#section-3.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC5829 describes a [version history](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5829#section-3.1) but does not suggest a return format.

First we assume you have a URL pointing to each version of the resource as in:

```
/path/to/resource/  - returns latest
/path/to/resource/v1 - returns version v1    
/path/to/resource/v2 - returns version v2
```

So what you actually want is to return a **collection of links**.
The best representation for this is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270469/what-is-the-best-json-schema-to-use-for-a-collection-of-http-links)

[RFC7089 - HTTP Framework for Time-Based Access to Resource States - Memento](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7089) describes a similar thing called a *time-map* and suggests using [application/link-format (RFC6690)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6690).
An example of this is given on [page 36](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7089#page-36):

```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2010 00:06:50 GMT
   Server: Apache
   Content-Length: 4883
   Content-Type: application/link-format
   Connection: close

    <http://a.example.org>;rel="original",
    <http://arxiv.example.net/timemap/http://a.example.org>
      ; rel="self";type="application/link-format"
      ; from="Tue, 20 Jun 2000 18:02:59 GMT"
      ; until="Wed, 09 Apr 2008 20:30:51 GMT",
    <http://arxiv.example.net/timegate/http://a.example.org>
      ; rel="timegate",
    <http://arxiv.example.net/web/20000620180259/http://a.example.org>
      ; rel="first memento";datetime="Tue, 20 Jun 2000 18:02:59 GMT"
      ; license="http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/",
    <http://arxiv.example.net/web/20091027204954/http://a.example.org>
       ; rel="last memento";datetime="Tue, 27 Oct 2009 20:49:54 GMT"
       ; license="http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/",
    <http://arxiv.example.net/web/20000621011731/http://a.example.org>
      ; rel="memento";datetime="Wed, 21 Jun 2000 01:17:31 GMT"
      ; license="http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/",
    <http://arxiv.example.net/web/20000621044156/http://a.example.org>
      ; rel="memento";datetime="Wed, 21 Jun 2000 04:41:56 GMT"
      ; license="http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/",
    ...
```

link-format is just the same format for links used in http for the link header itself but with whitespace removed (contrary to the example above!).

link-format may be more alien than JSON to API clients, so you might consider returning some kind of JSON document via content-type negotiation. There is no standard format for representing a collection of links in JSON (or rather there are several competing standards with different strengths and weaknesses). A reasonable overview is [Mark Nottingham's blog](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/11/25/linking_in_json). Though this is old at the time of writing, the formats he mentions are still the formats you will come across if you search for suggestions.
A good suggestion might be *HAL+JSON*. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language) and the [draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) (note the draft is expired but the link is not).
Using this a version history would look something like:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": { "href": "/versions" },
    "first": { "href": "/foobar/version1", "datetime": "2019-01-01T12:00:00Z" },
    "memento": { "href": "/foobar/version2", "datetime": "2019-01-02T12:00:00Z"  }
    "latest": { "href": "/foobar/version3", "datetime": "2019-01-03T12:00:00Z"  }
  }
}
```

I've added the datetime attribute here (possibly incorrectly) to represent a version time and used [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) format (which is my personal preference).

For both formats suggested here, you may want to consider carefully what relation names to use - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59176515/1569204

Comment: Accepting my own answer until/unless someone provides a better one